# python social auth get access_token not work in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, python-social-auth

I try get user's access_token like this way:

```
social = g.user.social_auth.get(provider='twitter')
token = social.extra_data['access_token']
```

but get error

```
TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'provider'
```

I'm use Flask==0.10.1 and python-social-auth==0.2.1 (update is not desirable).
Help me receive user's access_token in flask app please.

Answer (score 1):

g.user.social_auth is a SQLAlchemy object, so you need to treat it as such. @juzten was close. Try the following:

social = g.user.social_auth.filter_by(provider='twitter').first()

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the docs, try changing .get to .filter

```
social = g.user.social_auth.filter(provider='twitter')
```

Comment: No, absolutely nothing changes